# CommandLineParser: Required only if a value of another option is equal to?

Tags: c#, command-line-parser

Using https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline

I would like to set an Option as "Required" if the value parsed from another Option is equal to a particular value.

```
    [Option('f', "foo", Required = true, HelpText = "Name of process")]
    public string Foo{ get; set; }

    [Option('b', "bar", Required = ( Foo == "egg" ), HelpText = "Name of process")]
    public string Bar{ get; set; }
```

Comment: use "Verbs" instead ...

Comment: [like this](https://dotnetfiddle.net/ntrNl3) ... for common you can define base class for option

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible since .NET `Attribute` class has some restrictions to what kinds of arguments may be used with. **You have to use a constant expression** where you set the `Required` property. Your line

```
[Option('b', "bar", Required = ( Foo == "egg" ), HelpText = "Name of process")]
```

raises the explanatory compiler error (assuming `Foo` is a static property):

> **CS0182: An attribute argument must be a constant expression**, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute
> parameter type.